# Стилизация ползунка в виде круга

Tags: javascript, html, css

Можно ли обычный `input [type=range]` стилизовать вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Идей как это сделать, не используя кучу-малу `div`'ов вообще нет.

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="0.1" value="0"/>
```

Comment: думаю, что только SVG/Canvas + JS Вам поможет

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 3):

```js
$("#slider").roundSlider({
    width: 10,
    handleSize: "+16",
    value: "25"
});
```

```css
@import url('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.roundslider/1.0/roundslider.min.css');


.rs-control .rs-path-color {
    background-color:#dfdfdf;
  border-color: #3f3f3f;
}

.rs-handle {
  background-color: #3f3f3f;
}

.rs-bar .rs-seperator {
  display: none;
  border-color:#dfdfdf;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.roundslider/1.0/roundslider.min.js"></script>

<div id="slider" class="rslider"></div>
```

Comment: в этом варианте реализации, разве не используется "куча мала дивов"?

Comment: @Дмытрык Глянь в код элемента. Используется.